# Relative motion. Setting course of closest approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, relative-motion

Let $r_{P/Q}$ be the position vector of $\overrightarrow P$ relative to vector $\overrightarrow Q$ and $v_{P/Q}$ the velocity vector of $\overrightarrow P$ relative to $\overrightarrow Q$.

Suppose $|v_Q| > |v_P|$ and you want to set the direction of $v_P$ such that $|r_{P/Q}|$ becomes minimal at some point in time. According to the text I have, doing so requires that $v_P \cdot v_{P/Q} = 0$

[image]

Sorry for the horrendous image but I hope the idea is clear. $v_P$ could be any direction and the blue circle represents all possible directions of $v_p$

Anyway, my problem lies in that I do not understand why this is the necessary condition for the closest approach.

Could someone enlighten me?

If you know of a resource containing information relevant to this question, that would also be great.

Edit: I would add more detail but unfortunately there isn't much more that I know. Of course there are two angles where this works and I guess you choose the one depending on the initial positions of the two objects.

Edit: I'm really sorry but I didn't label the image properly which resulted in the post being confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{v}_P$ is parallel to $\vec{v}_Q$ and $|\vec{v}_Q| > |\vec{v}_P|$ then the distance will always increase. So minimizing the component of speed parallel to the motion of *Q* is critical. This is stated as $\vec{v}_Q \cdot \vec{v}_P = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to get you started:

First, consider a Galilean referential in which the problem is simpler and assume some fixed $v_P$, without taking care of its magnitude.

Second, use what you know of the distance between a line and a point (projection).

Third, minimize the distance between the line and point wrt $v_P$ under the contraint that $|v_P|<|v_Q|$.

Comment: I am sure that it is $v_{P/Q}$ which is defined as $v_P - v_Q$. Should I post the example given in the book?

Comment: @user110503: The formula as you give it does not seem to be very meaningful, but the problem is not hard and following the steps I gave, you should be able to solve it and compare with your book's explanations.

Comment: Well, my book doesn't have an explanation; just one example of it being done. Also, since the original post was not clear, are you sure the steps you give are still pertinent? I say this because $r_{P/Q}$ is something you would use to find the closest approach (in $r_{P/Q} \cdot v_{P/Q}$), but in this case I want to work out the direction to set to find the closest distance of all possible distances.

Comment: I had wringly understood. Edited

Comment: Thank you but I still do not understand. I am not trying to minimize the distance, I'm trying to set the direction. Your post suggests to me that you are attempting to do the former. Fix $v_{P}$ i.e. consider the motion wrt to $P$. Then use the fact that the distance is minimum when $r_{Q/P}$ and $v_{Q/P}$ are perpendicular.

Comment: To clarify above, I'm not trying to find the minimum distance, I'm trying to set the direction which will give me the minimum, not necessarily knowing what that minimum will be. The method I attempted to show was the way that should be done but as I said I do not understand why the conditions give the correct direction.